# Using "other" before singular countable nouns

Tags: adjectives, determiners

Grammar resources say the word *other* is used  before only plural nouns as a determiner, but I met the following sentence in my grammar book so I'd like to ask if it is grammatically correct to use the word other before singular nouns?

> Is there any other reason not to go?

It doesn't sound grammatically wrong but how can we explain it?

---

http://www.grammarbank.com/forms-of-other.html

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/other-others-the-other-or-another

Comment: What grammar resources? Surely they list the adjective *other*?

Comment: Thanks for editing to include links to those two resources.  Unfortunately, neither of those pages is correct :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second resource you list, Cambridge, stipulates:

> If we use *other* before a singular countable noun, we must use another determiner before it

*Any* is [a determiner](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/any) (Oxford dictionary), thus your sentence follows this rule.

The sentence

> ? Is there other reason not to go?

would be ungrammatical according to this rule.

Similarly, the first of the following is correct, but not the second:

> 1 Do you have any other toy my son might like?
>
> *2 Do you have other toy my son might like?

Comment: incidentally ,  any is not used before the singular countable nouns either but it is not problem if they are used both at the same time.

Comment: @Mrt Well, as a native speaker I can't agree with that, since the following is fine *Do you have any toy my son might like?*

Comment: Absolutely. *Is there **any man** here who disagrees?* In practice, of course, the requirement for an article is usually covered by, say, *Do you have **another** way of explaining the usage?*

Comment: @AlanCarmack yes your sentence sounds natural but could "any"  be  used as " indefinite quantity" in your example more than determiner according to http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/any

Comment: @Mrt Both uses of *any* that Cambridge is talking about there are *any* as a *determiner*. Determiners can refer to quantities (*some*, *no*, *many*, etc.).

Comment: As far as which can be used  in an interrogative, the OED gives the following example:  *Do you have **any** reason to think that your seed is capable of begetting a male child?* This does not refer to an indefinite quantity but to "an unspecified member of a particular class"  (OED, Oxford English Dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to AlanCarmack's answer, I think 'some/any other', when followed by a singular noun, is interchangeable with 'another'.  So you can say:

There's another reason not to go =  There is some other reason not to go.

These sentences in the interrogative are as follows:

Is there another reason not to go? = Is there any other reason not to go?

However, it's more common to use another than some/any other. Also, it's more common to use a plural noun after some/any other,  but you cannot use a plural noun after another.